# How to pass different object type for same method instead of writing two methods with same functionality and return type in java

Tags: java, java-8

here is my methods i want to make it dynamic which should accept class type as parameter and then i can use that in my predicate i have tried using instanceof but didnt work

```
public static String setStatus(List<SmeObject> s) {
    String finalStatus = "";
    Predicate<SmeObject> ifAllCompleted = x.getStatus().equals("Completed");
    Predicate<SmeObject> ifAllNotStarted = x.getStatus().equals("Not Started");

    if (s.stream().allMatch(ifAllCompleted)) {
        finalStatus = "Complete";
    } else if (s.stream().allMatch(ifAllNotStarted)) {
        finalStatus = "Not Started";
    } else {
        finalStatus = "In-progress";
    }
    return finalStatus;
}

public static String setStatus(List<ControllerObject> s) {
    String finalStatus = "";
    Predicate<ControllerObject> ifAllCompleted = x.getStatus().equals("Completed");
    Predicate<ControllerObject> ifAllNotStarted = x.getStatus().equals("Not Started");

    if (s.stream().allMatch(ifAllCompleted)) {
        finalStatus = "Complete";
    } else if (s.stream().allMatch(ifAllNotStarted)) {
        finalStatus = "Not Started";
    } else {
        finalStatus = "In-progress";
    }
    return finalStatus;
}
```

Comment: Do these two types implement a common interface? Or they are completely independent?

Comment: Why are you not using an enum for status-flags?

Comment: @akuzminykh i have used enum in my program while posting question i have used string

Comment: @mAnouti they are completely independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ControllerObject` and `SmeObject` share a common parent that exposes the `getStatus()` method, then you may want to make your method take a list with a `List<? extends CommonObjectSuperType>`:

```
public static String setStatus(List<? extends CommonObjectSuperType> s) {
    String finalStatus = "";
    Predicate<CommonObjectSuperType> ifAllCompleted = x.getStatus().equals("Completed");
    Predicate<CommonObjectSuperType> ifAllNotStarted = x.getStatus().equals("Not Started");

    ...
}
```

If, however, `ControllerObject` and `SmeObject` do not have a common parent that exposes `getStatus()` and you can't change them, then you're left with the option of making the caller send in a predicate by making the method generic:

```
public static <T> String setStatus(List<T> s, Predicate<T> allCompletedTest,
        Predicate<T> allNotStartedTest) {
    //use incoming predicates instead of creating them in the method
    ...
}
```

Then the caller will create the predicates in the context of the actual type.